# In Apple OS X's Calendar app, how to trigger an alert at the end of the event?

Tags: calendar, applescript, automator

If the event is one hour long, you can have the alert start one hour after the event. However, if you then change the event to be two hours long, the alert will then occur in the middle of the event unless you also edit the timing of the alert.

Another way to accomplish this is to have another event right after the first event, and have the alert go off at the start of the second event. However, each time you change the time of the first event, you'll also need to change the time of the second.

What I am looking for is a way to have the trigger time be the end of the event, even if you subsequently change the duration of the event, without any additional steps. Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this?

Comment: is this for a programatic solution? EventKit or CalenderKit

Comment: I was actually hoping to just be able to do it within the app itself, although I'd be fine with a programatic solution.